# What's the name of something without water that we heat (e.g., in the microwave) and place it in the bed to stay warm?

Tags: vocabulaire

What's the name of something we heat (e.g., in the microwave) and place it in the bed to stay warm? I'd use *bouillote* if it contains water, but what if it doesn't contain any water?

Example:

[image]

Comment: I would use the same term and the Larousse dictionary says: "Récipient étanche que l'on remplit d'eau chaude, **ou appareil électrique utilisé pour réchauffer un lit, une personne**.". It's not an electric device but since its purpose is to warm the bed I guess it's OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [***chaufferette***](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaufferette):

TLFi:

> *Ustensile, appareil de différentes formes destiné à chauffer une partie du corps ou un objet à l'aide de substances chaudes (braise, cendre, eau chaude), ou selon des procédés plus modernes (électricité notamment).*

As commented, ***bouillotte*** would also fit.

There used to be a specific and possibly regional term for it, *[**moine**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moine)*, but I guess it has been lost nowadays.

> Appareil formé d'un cadre en bois où l'on suspend un réchaud de braises et servant à chauffer les lits. *Lit que bassinait en votre absence un «moine» − c'est ainsi qu'on appelle là-bas [à Lamalou-le-Haut] un réchaud qu'un ingénieux système d'arceaux suspend entre les draps écartés* (Gide, Si le grain, 1924, p. 428) .
> 2. P. ext. Objet quelconque servant à chauffer les lits. *Après (...) la femme dessert, fait son petit train train, la couverture, le moine, et quand elle est couchée, la place chaude, on tombe dans le tas* (A. Daudet, Sapho, 1884, p. 189). *Elle s'a frotté d'onguent et couchée avec un moine sur les reins* (Arnoux, Seigneur, 1955, p.46).